# Append a textfield value to a different textfield on change of first textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want help on how to append the value of textbox1 to textbox2 when the value of textbox1 changes

```
$(function () {
    $('#textbox1').on('change', function () {
        $text1 = $('#textbox1');
        $text2 = $('#textbox2');
        $text2.val($text2.val() + ' $text1');    
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean like `$text2.val($text2.val() + $text1.val());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be `$text1.val()` just as you are with `$text2`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#textbox1').on('change', function () {
        $text1 = $('#textbox1');
        $text2 = $('#textbox2');
        $text2.val($text2.val() + $text1.val());    
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working.  It may be that you're expecting it to change when you enter text which is not the case with an input element.  If you change the text and hit enter then it will update the other input element.  You may want to change the event to be keyup, keydown or keypress.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for the above example (https://jsfiddle.net/xnv73v5e/) and here's one for keypress (https://jsfiddle.net/eqLdx36r/)